# What is the way of using transaction with ReactiveMongo?

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I am trying to use transaction with reactivemongodb in playframework. How can I do this  or is there any documentation available for playframework ?

Comment: There is nothing specific about play framework for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentation you can find example how to use MongoDB >4 transactions.

```
import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }

import reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument

import reactivemongo.api.DefaultDB

def testTx(db: DefaultDB)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Unit] = 
  for {
    dbWithSession <- db.startSession()
    dbWithTx <- dbWithSession.startTransaction(None)
    coll = dbWithTx.collection("foo")

    _ <- coll.insert.one(BSONDocument("id" -> 1, "bar" -> "lorem"))
    r <- coll.find(BSONDocument("id" -> 1)).one[BSONDocument] // found

    _ <- db.collection("foo").find(
      BSONDocument("id" -> 1)).one[BSONDocument]
      // not found for DB outside transaction

    _ <- dbWithTx.commitTransaction() // or abortTransaction()
      // session still open, can start another transaction, or other ops

    _ <- dbWithSession.endSession()
  } yield ()
```

Comment: Thanks for your assist. I used this but I did not notice the version recommendation. That is why it was not working. Thank you again.

Comment: what if the `coll.insert.one fails`, do you have to call abortTransaction explicitly in a .recover or?

Comment: There is an official documentation about [transaction semantic](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/core/transactions/#transactions-in-applications).